# How to make the highlighted matches (NSRegularExpression)?

Tags: ios, regex, nsregularexpression

I want to make the matches were blue in TextView.

```
NSString *text = @"Except as contained in #wep this notice, the name of a copyright #ololo holder shall not be used in  #pewpewpew advertising or otherwise to #promote";

NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"#\\w*" options:0 error:NULL];
NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:text options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [text length])];
NSLog(@"count %d", matches.count);

for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {
    NSRange matchRange = [match range];
    NSString *match = [text substringWithRange:matchRange];
    NSLog(@"Matched string: %@", match);
}
self.myTextView.text = text;
```

Comment: Use `NSMutableAttributedString`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to create `NSAttributedString` and then apply font as per range and set attributedText to your `UITextView` not a simple text.

your code should look like below.

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attrib = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:text];

for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {
    NSRange matchRange = [match range];
    NSString *match = [text substringWithRange:matchRange];
    NSLog(@"Matched string: %@", match);
    // set your rgb color here which you want i added blue color.
    [attrib addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName
                   value:[UIColor blueColor]
                   range:matchRange];
}
// set attributed text not a normal text.
self.myTextView.attributedText = attrib;
```

Maybe this will help you.

Comment: OK. And how to make matches of a button?

Comment: mean cant understand.

Comment: matches that were as buttons(UIButton)

Answer (score 0):

```
self.myTextView.attributedText = // your attributed string here
```